# Crear mis propios componentes en materialize

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, materialize

Estoy creando un proyecto propio con Laravel 8 y bueno, he diseñado mi propia `template` de un menu. Lo hice desde 0. Y bueno, ahora queria implementar `Materialize`, porque tiene algunos componentes que me gustaria usar. El problema, es que al integrar Materialize al proyecto, todo el CSS y JS propio de mis componentes se va a tomar por c*lo. Ni siquiera estoy usando clases de `Materialize` todavia. Solo añadí los `CDN` y gran parte de mi propio css se pierde.

Aun quiero usar `Materialize` pero quiero seguir usando el template que ya he creado.

Sin la CDN de Materialize
[image: introducir el código aquí]

Con la CDN de Materialize

[image]

Comment: Es muy común que tus ajustes se pierdan por causa de la [*normalización*](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) de estilos que aplican muchas librerías y frameworks de CSS. Mi sugerencia es que siempre tomes en cuenta esta normalización en tu diseño, no sólo porque otros frameworks lo usan, sino porque te permitirá tener un diseño uniforme en todos los navegadores que soporten CSS. Saludos

Comment: Ni que hacer, tendre que volver a usar Bootstrap. Pensaba en practicar con Materialize, pero seria rehacer todo lo que ya tengo y no tengo tiempo. Muchas gracias por la aclaracion